# To create sum guessing game

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create sum game where the two numbers are randomly generated and the end user(my son) will try to answer it. If True to go to the next question which is another sum with randomly generated numbers. then after 10 question game ends.
Code Outline:

```
import random
for x in range(1):
  print(random.randint(1,100))

4+3=7  Good job.
4+3=6  Try again buddy.
```

## Thanks to [cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) this is what i needed. I would like to expand on this code and have counting the correct answers vs wrong answers and display it at the end such as this:

You answered 7/10 correct. That is 70% correct.

```
import random 

def guess_check(x, y):
    print("{} + {} = ?".format(x, y))
    ans = input(">")
    return int(ans) == (x + y)

games = 10
while games > 0:
    x=random.randint(1,15)
    y=random.randint(1,3)
    if guess_check(x, y):
        print("Bravo Adam. YAAAAAY") 
        games -= 1
    else:
        print("No no no. Wrong.")
        games -= 1
```

This is the my final version of the code.

```
import random 

name = input("What's your name: ")
games_played = int(input('How many games you want to play: '))
games = games_played
if games <= 20:
    print("Ok, Let's do this.")
elif games >= 21:
    print("No more that 20 Games.")
    exit()
def guess_check(x, y):
    print("{} + {} = ?".format(x, y))
    ans = input(">")
    return int(ans) == (x + y)
correct = 0
while games > 0:
    x=random.randint(1,15)
    y=random.randint(1,3)
    if guess_check(x, y):
        print("Bravo " + name + ". YAAAAAY") 
        games -= 1
        correct += 1
    else:
        print("No no no. Wrong answer.")
        games -= 1
print()
print()
print("Here are your results:\n")
print('You have ' + str(correct) + ' correct answers out of ' + str(games_played) + ' questions.\n')
percentage_correct = float((correct / games_played) * 100)
print('You have ' + str(percentage_correct) + '% correct.')
if percentage_correct >= 75 and percentage_correct <= 89.99:
  print('Good job.')
if percentage_correct >= 90:
  print('Wow. Excellent!')
if percentage_correct <= 74.999:
  print('Better luck next time')
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? Looks like you're missing a loop to 10? Asking for user input? Validating the answer against two random numbers?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, People appreciate if you ask problem you are facing but asking the whole solution is not a good idea, show how much you have done , where you have stuck. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to assign your random numbers to variables in order to check the sum or later input. I'd suggest doing that as two separate items, rather than use a loop to just print those out

Regarding other tasks, you'll need a loop to 10, and you can extract the function to check the numbers to make the code easier to read

```
import random 

def guess_check(x, y):
    print("{} + {} = ?".format(x, y))
    ans = input(">")
    return int(ans) == (x + y)

games = 10
while games > 0:
    x=random.randint(1,100)
    y=random.randint(1,100)
    if guess_check(x, y):
        print("Good job") 
        games -= 1
    else:
        print("Try again")
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks very much. It works.
Is there any way that when wrong to have exactly the same formula to try again. 
One more add on. Is there a way to count the correct answers on the first try but not the second and display at the end of the game.
Sorry I know it a lot but thinking that giving him feedback at the end would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
 def guessGame(numbers):
     count = 1
     while count <= 10:
        total = sum(a)
        print("Round:", count)
        guess = int(input("Enter your guess:"))
        if guess == total:
            if count == 10:
                return count
            print("****Good guess****\n")
            print("Press enter for next round")
        else:
            print("Sorry!!!")
            print("xxxxxxx Game End xxxxxxx")
            break;
    count += 1;


turns = guessGame(random.sample(range(1,100), 2))
if turns == 10:
    print("\n\n*********** Well Done!!! ***********")
else:
    print("\n\nxxxxxxxxxxxx Bettern Luck Next Time!!! xxxxxxxxxxxx")
```